# Initial Condition for Numerical calculation of differential equation with 3 steps

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Say we discretize some differential equation with the following iteration equation:

$\phi ^{n+1}(x,y)= \phi ^{n-1}(x,y) +f(x,y)\phi ^n$

(if you'd like some more specific example, let me know)

The problem is feeding this equation with two $\phi$ so we can start the iteration. We can assume that any continuous $\phi$ at a given instant is a part of a solution of the original equation, but two subsequent $\phi$ (even if very close) assumes a small evolution that might not be a solution of the original equation. Am I making any sense? To put the question in a more simple way: **What is the usual approach of creating suitable initial conditions for 3 steps iteration equations?**

Comment: Depends on your problem. If you mention your *actual* problem, we might be a bit more helpful...

Comment: I want to see some real iteration equation or the original differential equation? or both?

Comment: I don't know what you want, that's why I'm asking...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you asked. For the case of a PDE It would be like this:
To run the scheme in three times you need the initial condition (ie at time zero) and the boundary condition.
making n=0 use the contour to replace n=-1. The equation (or system of equations) will describe time n and the solution gives time n+1.
you will get time n=1 and o already has time n=0 so you can find future n.

this reference has examples:"MATLAB Codes for Finite Element Analysis" A.J.M. Ferreira

Comment: Damn. I have no idea what I was asking eleven years ago.

Comment: Lol m Sorry! I saw the question and answered, I didn't even look at the date.

Comment: haha hey, questions don't have expiration dates! this might help someone else some day